# Why js cookie being written only if I click button two times?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a button that should write a cookie once it's clicked and change button's `textContent`

```
<button id="menu-icon" onclick="writeCookie()">volume_up</button>
```

But it would write cookie only if I click it two times.

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 *1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } else {
        var expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}
function writeCookie(){
    let element = document.querySelector("#menu-icon")
    let state = element.textContent;
    switch(state) {
        case 'volume_off':
            element.textContent = 'volume_up'
            createCookie("default", "", -1)
            createCookie("default", true, 100)
            break;
        case 'volume_up':
            element.textContent = 'volume_off'
            createCookie("default", "", -1)
            createCookie("default", false, 100)
            break;
    }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen because your page is not fully loaded or element wrongly initialized.

If you are using jquery try `on()` method

```
<button id="menu-icon" >volume_up</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu-icon").on("click",function(){
       writeCookie();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: same behavior. Writes cookie only if I click button two times...

Comment: Your problem is not on click EventListener, check how you're checking if cookie exits

Comment: Anyway, cookies being written only if I click two times...

Comment: Whats your coding doing? cos you can archive this without setting cookes

Comment: I need to save some client's settings, but client could be not authorized. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: hmm i don't understand. can you try `localStorage.setItem("default", "someValue");` ? use local storage 

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_sessionstorage.asp

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `onclick="writeCookie()` from the html and add the following line in the js file.

```
document.document.getElementById("menu-icon").addEventListener("click", writeCookie);
```

You should also check the console log.